# How can I add Offline google maps on website that I am creating

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am building a website which will be used in sea with no internet access and I need to show google maps and draw a path on it.

Can you tell me how can I implement the offline google maps on the website?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to implement offline Google Maps, since that service contains large amounts of data which is also constantly updated. Moreover, using Google Maps for commercial purposes is a paid service which can't be charged offline.